# how to move specific files from one folder to another?

Tags: python, directory

Friends, I'm working with some folders and I'm having a hard time moving files from one folder to another. I tried to use the command shutil.move (), but I can only move one file or all that are present in the folder. I would like to move only a few files present in the folder. I thought about making a list with the name of the files, but it didn't work, could someone help me please?

follow my code:

```
import shutil

source = r'C:\Users1'
destiny = r'C:\Users2'
try: 
    os.mkdir(destiny)
except FileExistsError as e:
    print (f'folder {destiny} already exists.')
    
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:

        old_way = os.path.join(root, file)
        new_way = os.path.join(destiny, file)
        
        if ['arq1','arq2'] in file:
            shutil.move(old_way, new_way)
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail that "it didn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

```
from shutil import copyfile
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

source = '/Users/xxx/path'
destiny = '/Users/xxx/newPath'

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(source) if isfile(join(source, f))]
for file in onlyfiles:
    if ['arq1','arq2'] in file:
        src = source+"/"+file
        dst = destiny+"/"+file
        copyfile(src,dst)
```

If the file is already in the new directory it will automatically replace it

Comment: I'm sorry for taking a long time to answer! unfortunately this code didn't work, it gave me the following error:
`NameError: name 'listdir' is not defined`

Comment: @Lucas My bad forgot to import listdir from os, updated code should work now